# Issues with SKAction

Tags: swift, skaction

The top function works. I have a 5 x 5 board and while an array contains 100, I need to keep generating blocks to place on the board. The check smallest keeps the smallest number on the board stored as the smallest only making that block clickable. I am wanting to spawn the blocks over time, and the second function is how I tried but just crashes the app.

```
func generateAndCheckBlocks() {

    while smallestArr.contains(100){
        if placeBlocks() == true {
            checkSmallest()
        }
    }
}

func generateAndCheckBlocks() {

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let run = SKAction.runBlock {
        if self.placeBlocks() == true {
            self.checkSmallest()
        }
    }

    while smallestArr.contains(100){
        runAction(SKAction.sequence([run, wait]))
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you remove 100?  the wait will not pause your while loop,  so in 1 second, who knows what is going on

Comment: I replace the location of the 100 with the number that was randomly created in placeblocks. You are saying the problem is that the while loop doesn't pause for the runaction to complete? I thought it would have to complete in order to run while contains again?

Comment: did you test it out on simulator?  runAction should not be immediate, it processes during the update loop, which you are never getting to,  so now  you are adding millions of actions and eventually blowing the memory because you never leave the loop to finish the update

Comment: Yes I run it on my phone and it blows up. Any ideas on what I should change in order to correctly place the blocks over time?

Comment: I have an array full of the number 100 and if the array contains 100, that means that there are still spots on the game board because the numbers I generate are between 1-50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a weird approach you have going on,  you may have bigger issues then you think,  but I take it this is a learning experience,  so...

Instead of while loops,  when your game needs to start creating blocks, just do:

```
//Only call this once, not in a loop
func generateBlocks() {

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let run = SKAction.runBlock {
        if self.placeBlocks() == true {
            self.checkSmallest()
        }
    }
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([run, wait])), withKey:"blocks");


}
```

Then, you can do this in your update loop:

```
if(!smallestArr.contains(100))
{
    self.removeActionForKey("blocks")
}
```

Comment: This worked! I would up vote it if I had 15 reputation. I thank you so much I have been working at this for quite a few days.

Comment: honestly I do not even think you need the array,  you may wanna try and get rid of it also